# My YouTube video isn't proportional and won't center correctly in the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

The iFrame should be perfectly centered in the div that it's in. It has a bit more space on the right. There should be equal amounts of room on each side. Also, the iFrame should also have a fixed aspect ratio, but that won't work either. Please help. The full website that I'm viewing it from is [here](http://www.redstonegaming.com) Thank you, I appreciate it greatly!

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause(); // <-- another issue
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity linear 5.8s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.content
{
 opacity: .85;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
 z-index: 0; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position: relative;
 top:15%;
 left:15%;
 right:15%;
 width: 25vw;
 height:25vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.border-right
{
 border-right: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
.footer
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
 position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
 opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css"
    name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#">
              <p class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
      <div class="border-right feed-column">
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;" class="rusty text-center">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column">
   </div>
    </div>
 <div class="footer">vv</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css to make the video resposive.

Here I added a wrapping div also for the alignment.

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
font-family: Rusty;
font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
background-image: url(0.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-color: f7f7f7;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity linear 5.8s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
font-family: "Rusty";
color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.content
{
opacity: .85;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 80%;
z-index: 0; 
background-color: #CCCCCC;
padding: 10px;
height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
.video-wrap{
  margin: 20px;
}
.video-container {
position:relative;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
padding-top:30px;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
  border: 0;
}
.title
{
text-align: center;
font-size: 7vh;
text-decoration: underline;
-moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}
.border-right
{
border-right: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.text-center
{
text-align: center;
}
.footer
{
background: #CCCCCC;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
        <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Gaming</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Programming</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">YouTube</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Other</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
      </li>
      <li class="current-item">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="login">
        <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
  <div class="border-right feed-column">
    <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;" class="rusty text-center">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
    <div class="video-wrap">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feed-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">vv</div>
```